# How to store value from windows command line terminal in a variable?

Tags: bash, command-line

Is there any way to store the value from a command to a variable. I'm tring to store the value from script: sc query "Servicename" | find "RUNNING" into a variable so that I can check if the service is running or not. This command when executed return either
[image]

or

[image]

I tried using the following command:
VARIABLE=$(sc query "Servicename" | find "RUNNING")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The command required is not find but rather grep and so:

```
sc query "Servicename" | grep "RUNNING"
```

This will then give a return code of 0 if the service is running and 1 is it isn't

For more "belts and braces" to can use awk:

```
sc query "Servicename" | awk '/STATE/ { if ( $4 == "RUNNING" ) { exit 0 } else { exit 1 } }'
```

This pattern matches the output for STATE and then checks the 4th space delimited field for "RUNNING". If it finds the string, it exits with a return code of 0, otherwise 1.

Comment: I get error saying awk is not recognised as an internal or external command. Are you using command-line?

Comment: It looks like this is a Windows BATCH command and nothing to do with BASH?